# java.lang.NullPointerException with a POST call in Karate

Tags: cucumber, karate

I have a feature file like below:

```
*Feature: Create Quote in D365
  Background: 
    * def myFeature = call read('D365_Authentication.feature')
    * header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + myFeature.BearerToken
    * def random_string =
      """
      function(s){
      var text = "";
      var pattern = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
      for(var i=0; i<s; i++)
        text += pattern.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * pattern.length()));
        return text;
      }
      """
    * url '<somehost>'
  Scenario: Create Opportunity
    Given path '<path>'
    And def requestPayload = read('CreateOpportunity.json')
    And set requestPayload.name = 'Temp Opportunity From Karate ' + random_string(10)
    And set requestPayload.hsl_closedate = '2022-03-23T00:00:00.000Z'
    And header Content-Type = 'application/json'
    And request requestPayload
    When method POST
    Then status 204*
```

When running this, getting NullPointerException. Can anybody help me identify why this exception is coming.

Comment: sorry no one can help with this kind of question, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: why is this so? If you have some additional queries, you may reach out to me.

Comment: explained in the last paragraph in the link above.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to download the jar file specific karate version from https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/releases.

Please unfold the Assets link.

You can run the feature file so:

```
java - jar jarfinename -m xxx.feature
```